# preg_replace to preg_replace_calback using array

Tags: php

I'd to change the preg_replace code to `preg_replace_callback.` 
**preg_replace code**

```
function replaceChars($text) {
// $text should contain an HTML document/content.
// This will remove HTML tags, javascript sections
// and white space. It will also convert some
// common HTML entities to their text equivalent.

$search = array ("'&(quot|#34);'i",  
                 "'&(amp|#38);'i",
                 "'&(lt|#60);'i",
                 "'&(gt|#62);'i",
                 "'&(nbsp|#160);'i",
                 "'&(iexcl|#161);'i",
                 "'&(cent|#162);'i",
                 "'&(pound|#163);'i",
                 "'&(copy|#169);'i",
                 "'&#(\d+);'e"); 

$replace = array ("\"",
                  "&",
                  "<",
                  ">",
                  " ",
                  chr(161),
                  chr(162),
                  chr(163),
                  chr(169),
                  "chr(\\1)");

$text = preg_replace ($search, $replace, $text);
$text = html_entity_decode ( $text , ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8' );
return $text;
}
```

**preg_replace_callback code**

```
return preg_replace_callback (  ($search) , function ($matches) use ($replace) {
        return ( ( isset ( $replace[$matches[1]] ) ) ? $replace[$matches[1]] : '' );
    } , $text );
```

I'm getting the warning Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback in line no.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Of course you get a warning about the `e` regex modifier. You have it in the last entry in `$search`. The purpose of `preg_replace_callback()` is to replace the `e` regex modifier.

Comment: Thank you axiac. I don't get the warning if I remove the e modifier in the search array. But I'm not sure the exact purpose of that last entry in search array. You want to me remove it or should I replace with something else?

Comment: Errr... it's your code, do whatever you want with it but I'm afraid you need to change more than that to make the `preg_replace_callback()` version work as expected. Put a `print_r($matches);` in the callback function to see what it found and to find out how you need to change the code to make it work.